# to_json wrapping a single object in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra

In my API, I am converting an ActiveRecord object into json via:

```
user.to_json :methods => :new_messages
```

Using irb, when I execute this statement, I get:

```
{someAttr: someValue, ....}
```

which is perfect. This is a single object so it's not wrapped in an array. Now when I run this in sinatra app like this:

```
get '/api/users/:fb_id' do |fb_id|
    user = User.where :fb_id => fb_id
    user.to_json :methods => :new_cookies
end
```

It wraps it in an array!!! Like this:

```
[{someAttr: someValue, ....}]
```

How can I fix this, and more importantly, why?!?

Comment: How did you get the `user` in `user.to_json :methods => :new_messages`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply using [Hash.[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
 Hash[{a: :b}]
 # => {:a=>:b}
```

> and more importantly, why?!?

Which ORM are you using in the second example? If it's ActiveRecord, then `User.where :fb_id => fb_id` returns [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object which wraps into an array when you call `.to_json`. It can be fixed like so

```
get '/api/users/:fb_id' do |fb_id|
  user = User.find_by_fb_id(fb_id)
  user.to_json :methods => :new_cookies
end
```

Comment: The OP was referring to Sinatra in the second example, which AFAIK doesn't have `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sinatra by itself doesn't have ORM. I assumed that OP uses ActiveRecord since it's most popular.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
user = User.where :fb_id => fb_id
```

with this line:

```
user = User.find_by_fb_id fb_id
```